# WIX MSI : how to check available disk space

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to check available disk space before the installation.

When I try this condition (below), Windows Installer tells me that there is no available disk space !

It’s not true, there is more than 229 Go available on my disk.

```
         <Condition Message="Il n'y a plus de place disponible sur votre disque dur !">
         <![CDATA[Installed OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1)]]>
         </Condition>
```

Any ideas ?

Fabrice

Answer (score 1):

That OutOfDiskSpace property isn't valid unil after the CostFinalize action, and I assume that your "before the installation" means when it starts.

Your condition also appears to be the wrong way around. Those conditions need to evaluate to true for the install to proceed. So your install will proceed only if it's already installed, which doesn't make sense. Almost certainly you don't need to check Installed in a launch condition.

If you want to use OutOfDiskSpace then check for it after CostFinalize with a type 19 custom action that causes an error if it's set. Having said that, Windows will probably tell you the same thing during the install so there's no point.

In general, I wouldn't bother with a check like that. Windows will tell you if it runs out of disk space anyway as the install proceeds, which is the safest way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: If i want to check if there is at least 100 Mo available on disk, how can i do ?